# Running UFT scripts as part of CruiseControl CI process

Tags: continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net, cruisecontrol, hp-uft, thoughtworks-cruise

I have a requirement to run all my [UFT (Unified Functional Testing)](http://www.learnqtp.com/what-is-qtp/) scripts as part of my continuous integration (CI) process. We are using [CruiseControl](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/) to implement our CI process. I can't find any information helping me configure CruiseControl to invoke UFT scripts. Are there examples or information on how to do this?

Comment: Could you please explain what UFT is?

Comment: I've added some links to provide context on the technologies involved, updated the title and tags to be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

if you can call it via a command line, it can be done via CCNet.
just use the exec task
http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Executable_Task

Answer (score 0):

I just got presented with this task myself. This is what I ended up doing:

1. Created a batch.mtb file via the Test Batch Runner tool (*All Programs > HP Software > HP Unified Functional Testing > Tools > Test Batch Runner*) to run the tests required. This tool allows you to select which tests you want to run. The limitation is that the tests need to be saved in the file system.
2. Wrote a new CCNet project. The first task of it is an exec task that calls the UFT Batch Runner Command line tool ("*C:\Program Files (x86)\HP\Unified Functional Testing\bin\UFTBatchRunnerCMD.exe*"). Passed the batch.mtb file as an argument to the application.
3. Wrote a custom agent that processes the XML results generated by UFT batch runner and turns them into a custom XML report. Added a call to it as the second task of the project created on step 2.
4. Merged the custom XML report into the CCNet log and created a custom report plugin to display the report in the dashboard.
5. Installed CCNet on the UFT server. Add the project to **this** installation of CCNet, since it needs access to the local file system.
6. Added a server reference to the UFT server's CCNet on my main CCNet server. That way you can monitor the new UFT build from your main dashboard.

I don't know if there is a better way to go about it but this is what worked for me. I wasn't able to install UFT in the build box because of licensing limitations. This way is probably better since the QA team don't have to access the main build server when they have to update their tests. As the test catalog evolves, all that needs to be done to maintain this setup is 
to edit the batch file.

Another option to steps (1) and (2) is to point the command line tool to a specific folder in the UFT server file system structure and run all the tests found there. Based on your requirements, that may work out better for you.